# How to use Custom Actions with TypeScript only?

Tags: testcafe

The [documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404150/guides/advanced-guides/custom-test-actions) tells, that in order to use custom actions, you need to use a JavaScript based configuration file and define your methods.

In my case, I want to add a customMethod that needs already defined selectors, enums etc. everything in TypeScript.

Is there a good way to use TypeScript only for defining a custom method?

Unfortunately, `t.customActions` is readonly, so I can not add it myself and since there is not `t.addCustomActions` method or something, I'm unsure how to add custom actions via TypeScript only.

I'm using TestCafe 2.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't support config files of the TypeScript syntax. The only way is to create a config with the TypeScript syntax and compile it with TypeScript before running tests with TestCafe. For example:

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

testcaferc.ts

```
export = {
  browser: 'chrome',
  src: './test.js'
}
```

will compile:

testcaferc.js

```js
"use strict";
module.exports = {
    browser: 'chrome',
    src: './test.js'
};
```